# PoDoFo setup with eclipse , Linker error, undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, linker, podofo

I'm trying to set up PoDoFo for C++ in Eclipse
OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Podofo link - http://podofo.sourceforge.net/download.html

I downloaded the latest version and performed the following stpes

```
  mkdir podofo-build
  cd podofo-build
  cmake ../podofo
  make
  su
  make install
```

everything works fine till this point.
This create a **libpodofo.a** file in my /usr/local/lib directory

In Eclipse 
Under C++ linker I added Library search path(-L) as /usr/local/lib
and in Libraries(-l) I added podofo
[image: Screenshot for G++ linker in eclipse]

Then I ran a Hello world example for podofo 
Link : http://podofo.sourceforge.net/examplehelloworld_cpp.html

make all 
Building target: opencvtest
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o"opencvtest"  ./src/opencvtest.o ./src/podofo_test.o   -lopencv_imgcodecs **-lpodofo** -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d  -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpodofo.a(PdfEncodingFactory.cpp.o): **undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.2.5'**
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
makefile:45: recipe for target 'opencvtest' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opencvtest] Error 1

Ldconfig -p gives me following :
ldconfig -p | grep pthread.so
grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
    libpthread.so.0 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    libgpgme-pthread.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpgme-pthread.so.11

Can someone please help me getting rid of this error , what configuration should I add to resolve this, any suggested reads are also welcomed.

Please let me know if any other info is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You either need to build with the `-pthread` flag (including for linking), or explicitly link with the `pthread` library. I'm sure there are multiple duplicates here, something even a simple search should have turned up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I found this answer earlier also , but I'm having a hard time understanding how to this in eclipse (ie setting project properties in eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was asking exactly.
In eclipse go to Project->c/c++ build-> GCC C++ linker -> Libraries

under Libraries (-l) section add your library in my case it was libpthread.so.0 so you'll be adding pthread [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUOG0.png)

for anyone having problems with PoDoFo (ie only libpodofo.a file generated )
add the following libs  : 
podofo
pthread jpeg z fontconfig freetype